# Unix command to remove trailing zeros from file

Tags: unix

I have a file that contains numbers like

```
125.0
3.5
0.0
2.1
9.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

How can I remove the zeros at the end of the file?

Thanks!

Edit: expected output should be

```
125.0
3.5
0.0
2.1
9.0
```

Comment: do you have `0.0` in the middle of file?

Comment: What do you mean by trailing zeros?  Remove `.0` from end?

Comment: @kev Yes, updating posts to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `vim` installed, try this command in vim:

```
:%s/\(\n0\.0\)\+\%$//
```

- `\%$`: matches position end of file

---

If you want to process multiple files, try this command in bash:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    echo ':%s/\(\n0\.0\)\+\%$// | :wq' | vim -e $file
done
```

- `-e`: run vim in `ex` mode

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using GNU `sed`:

```
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\(\n0.0\)*$//' file.txt
```

If you have many files and want in-place editing:

```
sed -i ':a; N; $!ba; s/\(\n0.0\)*$//' *.txt
```

Results:

```
125.0
3.5
0.0
2.1
9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -p0777e's/(?:0.0\n)*$//' file.txt
```

For multiple files

```
perl -i -p0777e's/(?:0.0\n)*$//' *.txt
```

For big files you can consider try this version:

```
tac file.txt | perl -pe '/^0\.0$/ and do{$_=<>; redo} or $x=1 unless $x' | tac
```